# How to search for uses of a type name in Visual Studio without getting false positives?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, visual-studio-2005

I need to find all instances of type xxx::Box in a VC++ solution. Searching for "xxx::Box" is easy, but often the namespace isn't used... searching for "Box" also matches

- `GetBoundingBox()`
- `*pBox`
- `//how  many Boxes`
- etc

I was wondering if the weird VS regex searching could help me, but I'm not sure. How can I only search for `Box` when it could be at the start of a line, or a parameter type, etc?

Comment: `^Box|.*Box\([^)]*?\)`? Matches Box at the start of string *or* as a part of a function name.

Comment: Not sure about VS 2005 but later versions of VS have a FindAllReferences function which seems to serve your purpose. It wasn't bound in 2013 so I had to bind it through the hotkey settings, again not sure about where it would be in 2005.

Comment: "Find All References" exists but is not trustworthy... part of the intellisense bugginess IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (denoted by `\b`) around the literal `Box` to only match the word "Box" (and not "Boxes" or "pBox" or some other prefix/suffix):

```
\bBox\b
```

Comment: Using a standard Regex maybe - but this is a VS-specific question. However It turns out `<Box>` does the same thing, in VS2005 at least.

Comment: @John If you check the *Use Regular Expressions* checkbox in the *Find and Replace* dialog, your search text will be interpreted as a regular expression. You can then simply use `\b` as is. Anyway, I didn't know about the angle brackets in `<Box>` so far.

Comment: Yes, but as I said VS doesn't _use_ standard Regex.

Comment: @John Thanks, I'm aware, but according to my tests, my expression works just fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: Oh, weird. I'm sure I did and it didn't work as expected - so I looked and found `<` did the same thing. Curious. Either way your answer got me where I wanted to be!